# Updating an AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation via change set

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I keep running into the following error when attempting to update an EIPAssociation via a change set:

```
Interface: [eni-04740b9f34d1d75dc] in use. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidNetworkInterface.InUse; Request ID: 3bfa13f2-abe5-4bb5-80aa-183605d3dfde)
```

Basically, I changed my resource to reference a value passed in as a parameter instead of an EIP that is created in the same CFT.

Old:

```
   "EIPAssociation": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation",
        "Properties": {
            "AllocationId": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "EIP",
                    "AllocationId"
                ]
            },
            "NetworkInterfaceId": {
                "Ref": "NetworkInterface"
            }
        },
        "DependsOn": "EC2Instance"
    },
```

New:

```
"EIPAssociation": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation",
        "Properties": {
            "AllocationId": {
                "Ref": "EIPAllocationID"
            },
            "NetworkInterfaceId": {
                "Ref": "NetworkInterface"
            }
        },
        "DependsOn": "EC2Instance"
    },
```

In both cases, "NetworkInterface" is created within the CFT while in the first example "EIP" is created within the CFT and the second example "EIPAllocationID" is passed into the CFT as a parameter. I can log into the console, unassociate the old EIP and associate the new one no problem. But when I attempt to do these via change set I get the annoying ENI in use error. Happens whether the instance is on or off.

Any idea how I proceed with this or what I am doing incorrectly?